# Is there a reason why my html refuses to call the javascript function from external .js file?

Tags: javascript, html

EDIT: Thankyou for the instructive responses, however, nothing has been succesful. Everything works as it is supposed to otherwise, but for some reason the `<body onmousemove = coordinate(event)>` does not call the functions from index.js (my external javascript file). I am using codesandbox.io, could this be the problem?

The javascript is succesfully called by the HTML to draw on the canvas, but whenever I try to refer to a function it does not call it. >:(

[image]

As the title suggest, I have been pulling my hair out trying to understand why the coordinate(event) function refuses to be called from my src file.

The idea is a simple one, as the cursor moves across the screen the x and y coordinates of the cursor should be logged in the text boxes. However, when I run this nothing happens.

**Javascript:**

```
let canvas = document.getElementById("gameScreen");
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'); //ctx = context

ctx.clearRect(0,0,800,800)

function coordinate(event) {
      
  var x = event.clientX;       
  var y = event.clientY;
  document.getElementById("txt_iX").value = x;
  document.getElementById("txt_iY").value = y;
}

// Box width
var bw = 800;
// Box height
var bh = 800;
//Square size
var sq = 20
// Padding
var p = 0;


for (var x = 0; x <= bh; x += sq) {
  
  for (var y = 0; y <= bw; y += sq) {
  ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
  ctx.moveTo(p, 0.5 + x + p);
  ctx.fillRect(x,y,sq,sq)

}}

function drawBoard(){
    for (var x1 = 0; x1 <= bw; x1 += sq) {
        ctx.moveTo(0.5 + x1 + p, p);
        ctx.lineTo(0.5 + x1 + p, bh + p);
    }

    for (var x2 = 0; x2 <= bh; x2 += sq) {
        ctx.moveTo(p, 0.5 + x2 + p);
        ctx.lineTo(bw + p, 0.5 + x2 + p);
    }
    ctx.strokeStyle = "green";
    ctx.stroke();
}
drawBoard();
```

**HTML:**

```
<html>
<head>

  <title>EXCEL_DM</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
   
  <script type=”text/javascript” src = "src/index.js"> </script>
  
  </head>
      
   <body onmousemove = coordinate(event)>              
        
        <canvas id = "gameScreen" width="800" height = "800" ></canvas>
        <br><br>
        <input id = "txt_ix" placeholder="txt_ix">
        <br><br>
        <input id = "txt_iy" placeholder="txt_iy">
       
   </body>  
   </html>
```

Comment: The DOM hasn't loaded when your script runs. Anything you try to get from the page before it loads (like `canvas`) will be `undefined`. Move this: `<script type=”text/javascript” src="src/index.js"></script>` just before the `</body>` tag, and see if that works. Or use [`defer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer).

Comment: or add `defer` attribute to script works sometimes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix your issue, there are three options. All of them will work, but you can choose which one you like the best.

---

**1. Moving `script` tag in `body`**

Right now, you are loading the JavaScript before the `canvas` element. This makes it difficult for JavaScript to find the element.

To fix this, simply move the `script` tag to the last line (before the `</body>` tag).

An example is below:

```html
<head>
  <!-- No more JavaScript here! -->
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Other HTML code here... -->

  <script src="src/index.js"></script>
</body>
```

---

**2. Adding the `defer` attribute**

If you didn't know, the `script` tag has an attribute called `defer`.

According to [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer):

> This Boolean attribute is set to indicate to a browser that the script is meant to be executed after the document has been parsed, but before firing `DOMContentLoaded`.

To add this, simply leave your `script` tag in the `head`, but change it so it looks like below.

```html
<head>
  <!-- Still in the head! -->
  <script defer src="src/index.js"></script>
</head>
```

---

**3. Add an `addEventListener` call to JavaScript**

If you don't want to change your HTML, then you can add an event listener in JavaScript, using the `DOMContentLoaded` event. For more information, visit [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event).

To implement this feature in your JavaScript code, simply add the following:

```js
// You can also use the function keyword if you're targeting older browsers.
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
  console.log("Hello, world! I'm loading after the DOM!");
});
```

*Keep in mind: `DOMContentLoaded` fires once the DOM has loaded, **not** after images, stylesheets, etc. have loaded.*

If you only want your script to run after *everything* has been loaded (images, stylesheets, etc.), then use the `load` event ([MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event)), like below:

```js
// You can also use the function keyword if you're targeting older browsers.
window.addEventListner("load", (event) => {
  console.log("Hello, world! I'm loading after everything!");
});
```